# Prove this generalization of Möbius inversion formula

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, complex-numbers, mobius-function, mobius-inversion

[Generalizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula#Generalizations) list this one as a generalization of Möbius inversion formula-

> Suppose $F(x)$ and $G(x)$ are complex-valued functions defined on the interval $[1, ∞)$ such that
> $$G(x)=\sum_{1\le n\le x} F\left(\frac xn\right)$$
> then
> $$F(x)=\sum_{1\le n\le x} \mu(n)G\left(\frac xn\right)$$

I know the normal Möbius inversion formula with the sum running over the divisors of $n$. But, I don't see how to prove this generalized version (although I feel like it won't be that difficult). Can someone please help me out?

Comment: It's basically the same. Substitute for $G$ in the second expression and get: $$\begin{align}\sum_{n\in[1,x]} \mu(n)G(x/n)&=\sum_{n\in [1,x]}\mu(n)\sum_{m\in[1,x/n]}F(x/(mn))\\
&=\sum_{p\in[1,x)}F(x/p)\sum_{n\mid p}\mu(n)
\end{align}
$$

Where we substitute $p=mn.$

Comment: To the extent there were errors, I think I fixed them. @SayanDutta

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I am sorry, but it seems I can't completely understand how you got the last expression from the second one... do you mind explaining it a little please...

Comment: The set of pairs $(n,mn)$ with $n\in[1,x]$ and $m\in[1,x/n]$ is exactly the same as the set of pairs $(n,p)$ where $p\in[1,x]$ and $n\mid p.$ They are exactly the same pairs.

Comment: [Apostol, *Introduction to Analytic Number Theory*, p. 39-40](https://books.google.fr/books?id=Il64dZELHEIC&pg=PA39), th. 2.21 and 2.22.

Comment: It might be worth writing it out when $x=6.1.$

Then:

$$\sum_{1\leq n\leq x} \mu(n)G\left(\frac xn\right)=\mu(1)G(x)+\mu(2)G\left(\frac x2\right)+\mu(3)G\left(\frac x3\right)+\\\quad\mu(4)G\left(\frac x4\right)+\mu(5)G\left(\frac x5\right)++\mu(6)G\left(\frac x6\right)$$

Comment: Now $$\begin{align}G(x)&=F(x)+F(x/2)+F(x/3)+F(x/4)+F(x/5)+F(x/6)\\
G(x/2)&=F(x/2)+F(x/4)+F(x/6)\\
G(x/3)&=F(x/3)+F(x/6)\\
G(x/4)&=F(x/4)\quad x/4\in[1,2)\\G(x/5)&=F(x/5)\\G(x/6)&=F(x/6)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Now, there is only one $F(x),$ with coefficient $\mu(1).$ 

What are the coefficients of $F(x/6)?$ $\mu(1)+\mu(2)+\mu(3)+\mu(6)=\sum_{n\mid 6}\mu(n).$

You can go through each case. What are the coefficients of $F(x/3)?$ $\mu(1)+\mu(3)=0.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews thanks a lot! I got it now!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The proof you are asking for is provided in your referenced WikiPage in the section *[Proofs of generalizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula#Proofs_of_generalizations)*.